# How do I run my game in full screen?

Tags: pc

I am using a lenovo z560 laptop but the game runs in the center of the screen but not in full screen. How do I make it appear in full screen?

Comment: You need to provide some more specifics otherwise this question will be closed for being far too vague.

Comment: Which game? 4char

Comment: Useless to go with other answers "it could be this or that" till the question is not clarified. At least give an example of one game not working in full screen!

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time, this is a setting you can change with your video card driver. On my laptop (Dell Vostro 1000) with Catalyst Control center installed, it's a pretty easy setting to change!

[image: Catalyst Control center]

If your graphic card isn't supporting Catalyst Control Center (because it's not an ATI or for whatever reason) there is probably an alternative (if you guys know, put it in here!). But it's your graphic card drivers that can fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You can generally either increase the resolution of the game through its settings, to match the resolution of your monitor, or set your monitor resultion to the default resolution of the game.  Normally games do the latter automatically, though if the resolution is small they will not not to avoid the game looking "blown up" and pixelated.

Answer (score 1):

First, check the options for windowed mode. Then if it is on, turn it off, then go to resolution try to make it max, then try pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> (<kbd>return</kbd>). Then it should be A-OK.

Answer (score 0):

Could also be that in the game's video options, you've checked off (or it's set by default) to run in windowed mode, and not fullscreen.